# Issues with HeapSort

Tags: c, algorithm, heap, heapsort

my task is to write the code to a heapsort according to pseudo code. It should heapsort the input Array (`4 3 2 5 6 7 8 9 12 1`) and then print it with the printHeap method. I know for a fact that the printHeap works, because I have already used it with a method called buildHeap (to build max heap binary trees, but you all already know that :)) and there it works flawlessly, so my problem lies in heapSort.

It sorts correctly and prints it in the way it's supposed to (parent -- child 1, parent -- 2, etc.), only issue is, that the biggest and last value, which is 12, suddenly turns into 24 and I have no clue why.

The code is the following:

```
void heapSort(int a[], int n){
int x = n+1;
int i;
int temp;
buildMaxHeap(a, n);
for (i = n; i >= 1; i--){
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a [0];
    a [0] = temp;
    x--;
    heapify(a, 0, x);
}

void printHeap(int a[], int n){

int i;
printf("graph g { \n");
for (i = 0; i < n/2; i++){
    printf("%d -- %d\n", a[i], a[left(i)]);
    if (right(i) < n){
        printf("%d -- %d\n", a[i], a[right(i)]);
    }
}
printf("}\n");
```

Output is following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 24
graph g {
1 -- 2
1 -- 3
2 -- 4
2 -- 5
3 -- 6
3 -- 7
4 -- 8
4 -- 9
5 -- 24
}
```

just so you know what exactly I have done, I will attach the while .c file here:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8BC629F201D2BC63!26268&authkey=!AFqVlm9AptiZ_xM&ithint=file%2cc

Really grateful for your help!

Cheers
Arik

Comment: I see no reason to think that your `heapSort()` function causes the set of values contained in the array to change, though you have not presented the complete code (any code you want us to consider should go *in the question itself*).  I suggest you employ a debugger to sort this out, but if you want help from us then we normally like to see a [mcve].

Comment: In `buildMaxHeap`, you're using an index `i` into array `a` whose value can be as high as `n`.  If `a` contains `n` values, then `i` should not exceed `n-1`.

Comment: When you enter the source data, your counter 'n' starts at zero and is incremented after each number is entered. If you enter ten numbers they are entered into array elements 0 through 9, but n is 10.  Add `n--;` after exiting the while loop. Now correct the printArray loop control using `i <= n;` and finally correct the printHeap loop control `i < (n + 1) / 2;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you observe an undefined behavior. (I personally on an online IDE got `0` instead of the `12`(`24`).)

Try:

```
void heapSort(int a[], int n)
{
    int x = n; /* changed from n+1 */
    int i;
    int temp;

    buildMaxHeap(a, n);
    for (i = n-1; i >= 0; i--){ /*<-- changed*/
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[0];
        a[0] = temp;
        x--;
        heapify(a, 0, x);
    }
}
```

Your arrays in almost all general purpose languages of today start with index `0`[For thorough information see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28array%29#Array_system_cross-reference_list).] You loop your array `for (i = n; i >= 1; i--)` wrongly and since the heap is max, don't process the first element and go out of bounds with the last. Although arithmetic with the `nth` element is defined in the standard, it is not meant so rather `< n` and some pointer work.

On a side note, you can use macros (`#define`s) for the `left`, `right` etc. functions to improve performance and ease the reading.

I hope that saves the day and the *AlgoDat* Exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot! your solution worked :)